# Push Notification (duplicate?)

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've seen other questions here about PNS, in terms of code, but how does the concept work?do I need to tell my client that they need a server? What goes in the server in terms of configuration/cron or whatever?

Please explain the process. Thanks a ton.

EDIT:

Please explain: Do I need to purchase an SSL certificate, or does Apple issue a "client" or " app" SSL certificate for me?

Comment: It has been 14 days.  You should accept an answer (John Skeet's is GOOD) and let the give him the bounty.  Do not make the bounty contingent upon any more detail.  You, as a developer, should be able to take it from where he left off.  PS:  Apple, during the process of creating the provisioning profile for the app, lets you download the SSL cert to use when speaking with their APNS servers.  No, you do not need to buy a SSL cert.  Comes with the $99 or $299 you paid for the privilege of being an iPhone Developer, as do all future certs you may need for APNS apps.

Comment: Jann- there is no need for the downvote or curtness. I wanted to clarify the important detail of the ssl cerificate. If you posted that as an answer, I might have accpted your answer. Sheesh. I as a developer cannot read into Apple's mind. How exactly am I to know that the certificate is Apple supplied?  The docs are log and winded and difficult to read thru. I did notice it but not until a very thorough review of the APNS guide. Please take your attitude elsewhere.

Comment: Oh and o quote your blog: "Here is the main problem: Apple documentation is like the documentation of many programming environments out there. They give details on the routine, the arguments to the routine and what it does. What they are woefully lacking in is well-written, error free examples of using that routine. Reachability, for example. There is documentation here for Reachability. Not really documentation, but an app that actually does compile. However, they leave it up to you for any kind of instructions on how..." Apple documentation isn't great. Puleeeez!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they basically will need a server. The steps go something like:

- User installs application
- Application asks for notification
- Phone talks to APNS, registers for notification for that app and gets a token back
- Application talks to your server to tell it the token
- The phone keeps a connection open to APNS to listen for notifications
- Periodically your server polls APNS for feedback, e.g. that the device has been disabled or the application has deregistered
- When you have a notification, your server tells APNS, and APNS tells the phone, which displays the notification

Note: you download the SSL certificate from Apple provisioning portal.

Comment: So I need to buy an SSL cert, or at least the client does? Sounds fun.

Comment: No, you do not need to buy a certificate. You generate a certificate from the provisioning portal.